# Why query is not returning value

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Why this query is not returning any value. There are values in my database with in that range

value input are

```
Date startDate = (Date) data.get("startDate");//2014-04-01  
Date endDate = (Date) data.get("endDate");//2014-04-30
int pagesize=10;
```

sql query is

```
String query = "select * from bill_details "
             + " where status=? "
             + " AND date(add_date) BETWEEN  " + startDate + "  AND  " + endDate
             + " order by add_date  desc limit " + pagesize;

ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, dataStatus);
System.out.println("Before execution");
res = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: What is this `where status=?`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Please see updated qs `status='active'`

Comment: You're leaving out single quotes around your date strings. At least without more info.

Comment: Use parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Can you post remaining  code too? because you may used `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `ExecuteScalar()`...

Comment: **[BEWARE OF SQL INJECTION](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. Also `BETWEEN` is rarely the correct operator for dates - [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), or [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: @VigneshKumar Please see updated codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Date startDate = (Date) data.get("startDate");//2014-04-01  
Date endDate = (Date) data.get("endDate");//2014-04-30
int pagesize=10;

String query = "select * from bill_details "
                + " where status=? "
                + " AND date(add_date) BETWEEN  ? AND ?"
                + " order by add_date  desc limit ?";

    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, dataStatus);
    ps.setDate(2, startDate);
    ps.setDate(3, endDate);
    ps.setInt(4, pagesize);
    System.out.println("Before execution");
    res = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: this `right one`, try this code, your not `set` the value from the `database`,..this problem of your code

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to concatenate a `Date` object to a `String`. Even if that works, then the date isn't surrounded with quotes in the query.

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to `format` the Date to a `String`.

Try this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

String query = "select * from bill_details "
               + " where status='active' "
               + " AND date(add_date) BETWEEN  date('" + df.format(startDate) + "')"
               + " AND  date('" + df.format(endDate) + "') " +
               + " order by add_date  desc limit " + pagesize;
```

Comment: So date is treated as string